# Change CSS position of absolute element

Tags: jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I wanna make a slider with [JQuery Swiper plugin](http://idangero.us/swiper/) that slider navigation's is out of swiper are. I have two element for navigation:

```
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
```

When I change `right` property of `.swiper-button-next` is go under parent element and doesn't show properly.

[Here is a JsFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/mooki/3rsp34mg/16/)

Here is an image of my expected result:
[image]

Comment: what are you giving to right property and what happening

Comment: for example when I change `right:10px` to `right:-10px`  the `.swiper-button-next` is go under parent element

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding in parent element and set the navigation position

```
.swiper-container {
   padding: 0 30px;
}
.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  left:0;
}
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  right:0;
}
```

Updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3rsp34mg/17/)

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. when you swipe, slides are pass under navigation elements. I want navigation elements are completely out of swipe area.

Comment: You can not set navigation element completely out of the area because `.swiper-container` have `overflow:hidden` attribute.. so that your navigation will hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give higher z-index of class .swiper-button-next